# Configuring Chrome to Ignore or Accept Specific Untrusted Certificates

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate

There are various **personal** websites and LAN addresses which I access through https. Obviously they're mine so they can be trusted, but since they all deploy a self-signed certificate, Chrome displays the "Your connection is not private" warning page, forcing me to do two mouse clicks before I enter each place.

Is there a way to set up Chrome to ignore or accept those certificates for those specific websites **only**?

I tried everything described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate) discussion, and nothing worked.

I'm using Windows 8.1.

Thank you all.

Comment: So you installed this self-signed certiifcates into the certificate store of the operating system you are using?  I just did those steps this morning with a non-trusted but valid certificate.

Comment: Are you referring to "certmgr.msc"? Because I did that as well. Maybe I'm doing something wrong with export procedure?

Comment: You need to make sure they go in the right section of certmgr otherwise they don't have the effect you want them to.

Comment: Local or machine? There is a difference

Comment: What would be the right section?